# Some doubts about accessibility service on android development

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm new on android development and I'm also blind so firstly I would learn many informations as possible about accessibility on Android.
I'm reading the official guide and I found that I can develop an accessibility service so my first question is: can I develop an accessibility service and then upload it somewhere to be called from an external software?
If yes, please tell me also where I can find a list of these accessibility services already developed; if no why should I develop an accessibility service as a single android project as written on the guide as a possibility?

Comment: Have look https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

Comment: Sincerelly, @Hemant-Parmar , I read this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html and my doubts born from this guide ... Thank for the new link ... I will read it!

Answer (score 1):

Helped by the guide linked @Hemant-Parmar I understand that there was a minsterunderstanding ... I thought that to develop an accessible app I should write an accessible service! The thruth isthat an accessibility service is an app that can help people with disabilities like talkback for blind!
So the correct answer is: yes, you MUST write an accessibility service as an external app and share it with all because it will be useful for someone with a disability!

For who want add accessibility capabilities on its app read here:

https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/accessible-app.html